# Build error in unity "sdk not found or invalid "

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to build my game in unity this error pop up:
[image]
Can you help?

I tried to build my game and expect to build successfully

Comment: Did you do as it says and check the paths are correct?  It also seems odd you have 5 viruses. You should fix that too

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new project and add just a cube or so and build the android apk with it, if it works then its something else but if it cant be built then you have a problem with the android sdk, i suggest you install again manually downloading all the needed components, I have fought this long time each time i had same issue and its hard to know how to fix really but its about installing again maybe from different source not just official android site but other people, there are people who found same issue and post the dk version that worked for them or so

Comment: ok let's see if it works

Comment: Sure, I hope it works, it was a pain for me really, but in the end you manage to achieve this, what I got is a certain fix I believe I got it from this video 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy_s4lurHYQ&ab_channel=BasementCreations

And it worked, itws hard because the official release of the sdk allows to install different versions and we dont know what is missing, so check the video and hopefully will work